# Calling protected API from VueJS/Express via Access Token?

Tags: vue.js, jwt

Apologies in advance if this is an obvious or silly question.

I'm trying to understand how Auth flows work within VueJS/Express Server to a protected API.

I have a situation where I need to call an API that is protected by JWT. To get this JWT, a client ID and secret is sent to an auth server which returns a token which is then passed in the header when calling the protected API, obviously these credentials need to be kept secure.

The app that is calling the API is an SPA built using VueJS and is running an express server to power it, the question I have is how do I call the auth server securely to get a JWT when I can't store a client ID or secret in the SPA app?

This doesn't require the user to authenticate as this data isn't protected for the users sake, it is more the data is specific for a products dataset that is only accessible to anyone with an app ID and secret, so there wouldn't be an "authorisation prompt" so to speak.

So can I use express in the backend to securely call the API? but if I do that, surely anyone can call my express instance when its running in Azure if they know the URL?

I've looked into a few authentication methods and ways of doing this but they all suggest that the user is prompted for authorisation rather than an app or SPA calling a protected endpoint with appID/secret combination.

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com suits the question more. Consider explaining your case further. There could be more than one way to do this depending on how it's supposed to work. " how do I call the auth server securely" - it's unclear what your concerns are. Secure from which trait?

Comment: Thanks @EstusFlask ! I think my main concerns are being able call the API from the express instance securely, because if I can call the express instance from my VueJS app, then what is stopping a rogue actor from doing the same?

Comment: There's no security on client side. Everything that browser app does can be done by a culprit by tampering existing app or mocking its behaviour. If you want to prevent api from being misused, consider additional security measures that would allow to rate limit a specific session/client. So user registration would be one of them.